# sys.objects get modfiy_date is showing empty table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get `name`, `create_date` and `modify_date` of procedures, table, functions, and views from `sql-server` using this query

```
use ecomm
select name, create_date, modify_date from sys.objects where type = 'U' and name = 'dbo.Users'
```

It is returning empty table instead of populating it with data. The query is correct, but I don't know why it is returning empty results.

Please correct me where I am going wrong.

[image]

My Database version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)
```

Comment: Try with sys.all_objects. Users table maybe seen as system objects in your db

Comment: The name would just be `Users`, `schema_id` (not schema name) is a different column. Try `WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users');`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thnks bro! I am now able to see the intended output